# Moving a maximized window between monitors without shrinking it

Tags: multiple-monitors, window

I work with 3 monitors (though one currently not supported by Ubuntu ATM, but I'm working on it), and in Windows I was using this program called "UltraMon", which enables many nice and useful tools and tweaks for working with multiple monitors.. one of the features of this program is that it allows to move a maximized window between monitors, and just drop it anywhere on the other monitor, and it stays maximized on the target monitor (actually it shrinks but immediately maximizes itself again - it probably recognizes that it was maximized on the original screen).
I really would like to achieve the same behavior in Ubunutu, as it really is a very nice and cool feature and it allows moving screen very intuitively, just "drag and drop".. I use it a lot when I'm working with several tabs opened on the browser, and I just want to detach one the tabs and throw in away in the other screen.

I'd really be happy if there is a built-in or external program\option to tweak the does this in Ubuntu (14.04). I really would like it to allow the "drop" of the window anywhere on the screen (just like I do in Windows...), and not just sticking it to the top, which is the default way of achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works with Ubuntu's Unity desktop, or if it's exactly what you are looking for but Using XFCE based Ubuntu distributions (Xubuntu and Ubuntu Studio.), you can do very much the same thing. If you grab the top bar of the window you can drag it to another display or even desktop, if you push the top bar to the top of that display then it will snap maximized to that display.

Comment: Actually it does work in Unity, but I find it less intuitive, as you have to remember to stick it to the top, instead of just throwing it around... Plus, what happens when you have 3-4 monitors, one of which is above the other screens - meaning there is no sticky top to push it against (I disabled the "sticky edges" option, I don't like it). I mentioned this is my question - last paragraph (I edited my question for that).