# Moving window to smaller monitor: in 23.04 the window needs to be small enough to fit within the smaller monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, window, window-manager, 23.04

In Xubuntu 22.10 I could drag a program/window from my main (large) monitor to either of my (same sized) smaller monitors, and it didn't matter what size the program/window originally was. If larger than the destination monitor, it would just spill over. This was never an issue - just doubleclick the window title to maximise it to the now-smaller monitor it's on. By way of substantiation, the answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458003/moving-a-maximized-window-between-monitors-without-shrinking-it) question confirms this used to be the behaviour.

In Xubuntu 23.04, I can't drag windows to a smaller monitor unless I first ensure both height and width are <= h & w of the destination monitor. Which means using alt+rightmouse to manually shrink the window to a small size, then dragging, then doubleclicking.

This is a bit of an annoying change. Does anyone know where this would be controlled, and whether I can change it?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you found a bug. Consider [filing a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: You could be right - though it might also be a deliberate choice. In either case, any guesses where I should aim the bug report? I suppose Window Manager is just within the *buntu family of programs, go Ubuntu general you think?